# Pattern Matching in Lists

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a UN voting dataset – taken from a CSV file – *where each row* is in following format:

```
{venue, session number, resolution code, descriptor, full date, year, month, day, topic, country, vote code, vote}
```

I would like to indicate the vote coincidence between the US and another country for a given year and 'topic.' Sample (*note that Botswana did not vote in res. '15294'*):

```
UNGA2009 = {{"UNGA", 63, 15294, "...", "30-Jun-09", 2009, 6, 30, "B", "Argentina", 3, "YES"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15294, "...", "30-Jun-09", 2009, 6, 30, "B", "Cuba", 3, "YES"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15294, "...", "30-Jun-09", 2009, 6, 30, "B", "United States", 1, "NO"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15295, "...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "F", "Argentina", 2, "ABSTAIN"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15295, "...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "F", "Botswana", 2, "ABSTAIN"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15295, "...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "F", "Cuba", 1, "NO"} , {"UNGA", 63, 15295, "...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "F", "United States", 3, "YES"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15295, "...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "H", "Argentina", 2, "ABSTAIN"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15295, "...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "H", "Botswana", 2, "ABSTAIN"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15295, "...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "H", "Cuba", 1, "NO"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15295, "...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "H", "United States", 3, "YES"}}
```

With output looking something like this:

```
{15294, 2009, "B", "Argentina", 0}, {15294, 2009, "B", "Cuba", 0}, {15295, 2009, "F", "Argentina", .5}, {15295, 2009, "F", "Botswana", .5}, {15295, 2009, "F", "Cuba", 0}, {15295, 2009, "H", "Argentina", .5}, {15295, 2009, "H", "Botswana", .5}, {15295, 2009, "H", "Cuba", 0}
```

Where 0 is non-coincidence of the vote, 1 is coincidence, and .5 is partial coincidence (when one country abstains and the other votes either yes or no). Does anyone have any ideas on what the best method would be?

Thanks Again,
Arebearit

Comment: It would help if you could give a small example of input and output that you desire from it.

Comment: Right. Input would be lists like these: `{{"UNGA", 1, 10044, "GAOR-1-66", "1-Jan-46", 1946, 1, 1, "F", 
  "United States", 3, "YES"}, 
{"UNGA", 1, 10044, "GAOR-1-66", "1-Jan-46", 1946, 1, 1, 
  "L", "Canada", 3, "YES"}}` And output would be, say, a list containing ones or zeroes to indicate coincidence or non-coincidence.

Comment: Do you really have a (Mathematica) Dataset or is this (only) a list. If you have a Dataset there is a good chance to get a simple solution.

Comment: I guess it is just a list of lists – in contrast to a native Mathematica dataset? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Is the intent to pass two specific countries and get a result pertinent to those two? Or are you trying for an "all-pairs" type of result? There may be better or worse approaches depending on which of these scenarios (if either) you wish to address.

Comment: Unfortunately I would like to generate a result pertinent to both the country, topic, and year – if that makes sense. In the end I am trying to generate 'percent coincidence' for two countries in a specific year on a specific issue. And for that I would need to know total number resolution votes common to the two countries for a given year and topic, and then the number of times their actual vote coincides.

Comment: This should be fairly easy, but anyone wanting to help you is first faced with the boring task of generating a suitable dataset to test with. If you include an example dataset in the question (say a dozen rows or so) you will be much more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't have V10, you can use a combination of `GatherBy` and `Cases` as follows:

First, define a helper function, `vF`, for aggregation of vote pairs:

```
vF[{"ABSTAIN", Except["ABSTAIN"]} | {Except["ABSTAIN"], "ABSTAIN"}] = .5;
vF[{x_, x_}] := 1;
vF[{x_, y_}] := 0;
```

and another helper function, `rearrangeF`, that rearranges the data for each *resolution code*, *year* and *topic* tuple. For each country except the reference country ("UnitedStates" in OP's example), `rearrangeF` replaces the `vote` of that country with the pair `vF[{vote, refv}]` where the `refv` is the vote of the reference country:

```
rearrangeF[ref_String: "United States"] := 
  With[{others = Cases[#, {__, Except[ref], _}], 
     refv = Cases[#, {__, ref, v_} :> v]}, 
    If[refv === {}, {}, Append[Most@#, vF@{Last@#, First@refv}] & /@ others]] &;
```

Next, take the relevant 5 columns of the data (columns 3, 6, 9, 10 and 12) and `GatherBy` the resulting data set by  *resolution code*, *year* and *topic*:

```
data2 = GatherBy[UNGA2009[[All, {3, 6, 9, 10, 12}]], #[[;; 3]] &]

{{{15294, 2009, "B", "Argentina", "YES"}, {15294, 2009, "B", "Cuba", "YES"}, 
  {15294, 2009, "B", "United States", "NO"}}, 
 {{15295, 2009, "F", "Argentina", "ABSTAIN"}, {15295, 2009, "F", "Botswana", "ABSTAIN"}, 
  {15295, 2009, "F", "Cuba", "NO"}, {15295, 2009, "F", "United States", "YES"}}, 
 {{15295, 2009, "H", "Argentina", "ABSTAIN"}, {15295, 2009, "H", "Botswana", "ABSTAIN"},
  {15295, 2009, "H", "Cuba", "NO"}, {15295, 2009, "H", "United States",  "YES"}}}
```

**Usage examples:**

Example 1:

```
Join @@ rearrangeF[] /@ data2
{{15294, 2009, "B", "Argentina", 0}, {15294, 2009, "B", "Cuba",  0}, 
 {15295, 2009, "F", "Argentina", 0.5}, {15295, 2009, "F", "Botswana", 0.5}, 
 {15295, 2009, "F", "Cuba", 0}, {15295, 2009, "H", "Argentina", 0.5}, 
 {15295, 2009, "H", "Botswana", 0.5}, {15295, 2009, "H", "Cuba", 0}}
```

Example 2:

```
Join @@ rearrangeFX["Botswana"] /@ data2
{{15295, 2009, "F", "Argentina", 1}, {15295, 2009, "F", "Cuba",  0.5},
 {15295, 2009, "F", "United States", 0.5}, {15295, 2009, "H", "Argentina", 1},
 {15295, 2009, "H", "Cuba", 0.5}, {15295, 2009, "H", "United States", 0.5}}
```

Example 3:

```
Join @@ rearrangeFX["Argentina"] /@ data2
{{15294, 2009, "B", "Cuba", 1}, {15294, 2009, "B", "United States", 0}, 
 {15295, 2009, "F", "Botswana", 1}, {15295, 2009, "F", "Cuba",  0.5},
 {15295, 2009, "F", "United States", 0.5}, {15295, 2009, "H", "Botswana", 1},
 {15295, 2009, "H", "Cuba", 0.5}, {15295, 2009, "H",  "United States", 0.5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understood you right now. Give it a try with (the famous) Dataset ;-)

```
keys = {venue, session number, resolution code, descriptor, full date,
year, month, day, topic, country, vote code, vote};
```

First we make strings from the keys:

```
keys = ToString /@ keys
```

Now we have the data: (*just your data*)

```
data = {{"UNGA", 63, 15294, "...", "30-Jun-09", 2009, 6, 30, "B", 
"Argentina", 3, "YES"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15294, "...", "30-Jun-09", 
2009, 6, 30, "B", "Cuba", 3, "YES"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15294, "...", 
"30-Jun-09", 2009, 6, 30, "B", "United States", 1, "NO"}, {"UNGA",
 63, 15295, "...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "F", "Argentina", 2, 
"ABSTAIN"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15295, "...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, 
"F", "Botswana", 2, "ABSTAIN"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15295, "...", 
"9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "F", "Cuba", 1, "NO"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15295,
 "...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "F", "United States", 3, 
"YES"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15295, "...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "H", 
"Argentina", 2, "ABSTAIN"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15295, "...", "9-Sep-09",
 2009, 9, 9, "H", "Botswana", 2, "ABSTAIN"}, {"UNGA", 63, 15295, 
"...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "H", "Cuba", 1, "NO"}, {"UNGA", 63,
 15295, "...", "9-Sep-09", 2009, 9, 9, "H", "United States", 3, 
"YES"}};
```

Now we build Rules (with a function, just for convenience)

```
makeRule[keys_, values_] := Rule @@@ ({keys, values}\[Transpose])
```

Next step - making an Association

```
temp = Association @@@ (makeRule[keys, #] & /@ data);
```

And finally... a Dataset

```
ds = Dataset@temp
```

Now you can simply extract data for the Dataset, e.g. all "NO" votes:

```
ds[Select[#vote == "NO" &]]
```

or summarize the votes of the grouped countries

```
ds[GroupBy[#country &]][All, All, "vote"]
```

or, or or.... Take a look at the documentation of Dataset.